# Using continuous curve without points

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

is it possible to use a curve without specific point to represent the data, the reason is that the data has too many points to display correctly.
This is what I have (It looks all messed up)
[image]
This is the kind of curve I wish to have
[image]

Here is the latex code x-axis(1-400) increased increased, y-axis converged to a value.

Here is the code with data

```
\documentclass[9pt]{article}
% GRAPHICS
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
xticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
every axis/.append style={
font=\sffamily,
  width=6.5cm,
    height=4.9cm
}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\begin{axis}[title=\textbf{QWS Dataset},
    legend pos=outer north east,
                ytick={0,0.2,...,1},
                legend pos=outer north east,
                legend style={draw=none},
                xtick={0,200,...,1000},
                scaled ticks=false,
                log ticks with fixed point={1000 sep=},
                axis x line=bottom,
                axis y line=left,
                axis line style=-,
                minor tick style={draw=none},
        ylabel = Optimality (\%),
        xlabel = Number of Generation
]
\addplot plot coordinates{(0,0.286803995268681)(0,0.293986647767033)(1,0.293986647767033)(2,0.293986647767033)(3,0.293986647767033)(4,0.296941042144544)(5,0.296941042144544)(6,0.840289302662629)(7,0.883725575957752)(8,0.883725575957752)(9,0.883725575957752)(10,0.883725575957752)(11,0.888401316547969)(12,0.888401316547969)(13,0.888401316547969)(14,0.888401316547969)(15,0.888401316547969)(16,0.888401316547969)(17,0.888401316547969)(18,0.888401316547969)(19,0.888401316547969)(20,0.888401316547969)(21,0.888401316547969)(22,0.888401316547969)(23,0.888401316547969)(24,0.888401316547969)(25,0.888401316547969)(26,0.888401316547969)(27,0.888401316547969)(28,0.888401316547969)(29,0.888401316547969)(30,0.888401316547969)(31,0.888401316547969)(32,0.888401316547969)(33,0.888401316547969)(34,0.888401316547969)(35,0.888549662438951)(36,0.888549662438951)(37,0.888549662438951)(38,0.888549662438951)(39,0.894067099804665)(40,0.894067099804665)(41,0.894067099804665)(42,0.894067099804665)(43,0.894067099804665)(44,0.894067099804665)(45,0.894067099804665)(46,0.894147773567333)(47,0.894147773567333)(48,0.901221579313708)(49,0.901221579313708)(50,0.901221579313708)(51,0.901221579313708)(52,0.913119929645424)(53,0.913119929645424)(54,0.913119929645424)(55,0.913119929645424)(56,0.913119929645424)(57,0.913119929645424)(58,0.913119929645424)(59,0.913119929645424)(60,0.913119929645424)(61,0.913119929645424)(62,0.913119929645424)(63,0.913119929645424)(64,0.913119929645424)(65,0.913119929645424)(66,0.913119929645424)(67,0.913119929645424)(68,0.913119929645424)(69,0.913119929645424)(70,0.913119929645424)(71,0.913119929645424)(72,0.913119929645424)(73,0.913119929645424)(74,0.913119929645424)(75,0.913119929645424)(76,0.913119929645424)(77,0.913119929645424)(78,0.913119929645424)(79,0.913119929645424)(80,0.913119929645424)(81,0.913119929645424)(82,0.913119929645424)(83,0.913119929645424)(84,0.913119929645424)(85,0.913119929645424)(86,0.913119929645424)(87,0.913119929645424)(88,0.913119929645424)(89,0.913119929645424)(90,0.913119929645424)(91,0.913119929645424)(92,0.913119929645424)(93,0.913119929645424)(94,0.913119929645424)(95,0.913119929645424)(96,0.913119929645424)(97,0.913119929645424)(98,0.913119929645424)(99,0.913119929645424)(100,0.913119929645424)(101,0.913119929645424)(102,0.913119929645424)(103,0.913119929645424)(104,0.913119929645424)(105,0.913119929645424)(106,0.913119929645424)(107,0.913119929645424)(108,0.913119929645424)(109,0.913119929645424)(110,0.913119929645424)(111,0.913119929645424)(112,0.913119929645424)(113,0.913119929645424)(114,0.913119929645424)(115,0.913119929645424)(116,0.913119929645424)(117,0.913119929645424)(118,0.913119929645424)(119,0.913119929645424)(120,0.913119929645424)(121,0.913119929645424)(122,0.913119929645424)(123,0.913119929645424)(124,0.913119929645424)(125,0.913119929645424)(126,0.913119929645424)(127,0.913119929645424)(128,0.913119929645424)(129,0.913119929645424)(130,0.913119929645424)(131,0.913119929645424)(132,0.913119929645424)(133,0.913119929645424)(134,0.913119929645424)(135,0.913119929645424)(136,0.913119929645424)(137,0.913119929645424)(138,0.913119929645424)(139,0.913119929645424)(140,0.913119929645424)(141,0.913119929645424)(142,0.913119929645424)(143,0.913119929645424)(144,0.913119929645424)(145,0.913119929645424)(146,0.913119929645424)(147,0.913119929645424)(148,0.913119929645424)(149,0.913119929645424)(150,0.913119929645424)(151,0.913119929645424)(152,0.913119929645424)(153,0.913119929645424)(154,0.913119929645424)(155,0.913119929645424)(156,0.913119929645424)(157,0.913119929645424)(158,0.913119929645424)(159,0.913119929645424)(160,0.913119929645424)(161,0.913119929645424)(162,0.913119929645424)(163,0.913119929645424)(164,0.913119929645424)(165,0.913119929645424)(166,0.913119929645424)(167,0.913119929645424)(168,0.913119929645424)(169,0.913119929645424)(170,0.913119929645424)(171,0.913119929645424)(172,0.913119929645424)(173,0.913119929645424)(174,0.913119929645424)(175,0.913119929645424)(176,0.913119929645424)(177,0.913119929645424)(178,0.913119929645424)(179,0.913119929645424)(180,0.913119929645424)(181,0.913119929645424)(182,0.913119929645424)(183,0.913119929645424)(184,0.913119929645424)(185,0.913119929645424)(186,0.913119929645424)(187,0.913119929645424)(188,0.913119929645424)(189,0.913119929645424)(190,0.913119929645424)(191,0.913119929645424)(192,0.913119929645424)(193,0.913119929645424)(194,0.913119929645424)(195,0.913119929645424)(196,0.913119929645424)(197,0.913119929645424)(198,0.913119929645424)(199,0.913119929645424)(200,0.913119929645424)(201,0.913119929645424)(202,0.913951685219313)(203,0.913951685219313)(204,0.913951685219313)(205,0.913951685219313)(206,0.913951685219313)(207,0.913951685219313)(208,0.913951685219313)(209,0.913951685219313)(210,0.913951685219313)(211,0.913951685219313)(212,0.913951685219313)(213,0.913951685219313)(214,0.913951685219313)(215,0.913951685219313)(216,0.913951685219313)(217,0.913951685219313)(218,0.913951685219313)(219,0.913951685219313)(220,0.913951685219313)(221,0.913951685219313)(222,0.913951685219313)(223,0.913951685219313)(224,0.913951685219313)(225,0.913951685219313)(226,0.913951685219313)(227,0.913951685219313)(228,0.913951685219313)(229,0.913951685219313)(230,0.913951685219313)(231,0.913951685219313)(232,0.926293607531258)(233,0.926293607531258)(234,0.926293607531258)(235,0.926293607531258)(236,0.926293607531258)(237,0.926293607531258)(238,0.926293607531258)(239,0.926293607531258)(240,0.926293607531258)(241,0.926293607531258)(242,0.926293607531258)(243,0.926293607531258)(244,0.926293607531258)(245,0.926293607531258)(246,0.926293607531258)(247,0.926293607531258)(248,0.926293607531258)(249,0.926293607531258)(250,0.926293607531258)(251,0.926293607531258)(252,0.926293607531258)(253,0.926293607531258)(254,0.926293607531258)(255,0.926293607531258)(256,0.926293607531258)(257,0.926293607531258)(258,0.926293607531258)(259,0.926293607531258)(260,0.926293607531258)(261,0.926293607531258)(262,0.926293607531258)(263,0.926293607531258)(264,0.926293607531258)(265,0.926293607531258)(266,0.926293607531258)(267,0.926293607531258)(268,0.926293607531258)(269,0.926293607531258)(270,0.926293607531258)(271,0.926293607531258)(272,0.926293607531258)(273,0.926293607531258)(274,0.926293607531258)(275,0.926293607531258)(276,0.926293607531258)(277,0.926293607531258)(278,0.926293607531258)(279,0.926293607531258)(280,0.926293607531258)(281,0.926293607531258)(282,0.926293607531258)(283,0.926293607531258)(284,0.926293607531258)(285,0.926293607531258)(286,0.926293607531258)(287,0.926293607531258)(288,0.926293607531258)(289,0.926293607531258)(290,0.926293607531258)(291,0.926293607531258)(292,0.926293607531258)(293,0.926293607531258)(294,0.926293607531258)(295,0.926293607531258)(296,0.926293607531258)(297,0.926293607531258)(298,0.926293607531258)(299,0.926293607531258)(300,0.926293607531258)(301,0.926293607531258)(302,0.926293607531258)(303,0.926293607531258)(304,0.926293607531258)(305,0.926293607531258)};
\addplot plot coordinates{(0,0.893138221303528)(0,0.897063840513733)(1,0.909783376964972)(2,0.909783376964972)(3,0.909783376964972)(4,0.909783376964972)(5,0.909783376964972)(6,0.909783376964972)(7,0.916174495807532)(8,0.916174495807532)(9,0.916174495807532)(10,0.916174495807532)(11,0.916174495807532)(12,0.916174495807532)(13,0.916174495807532)(14,0.916174495807532)(15,0.916174495807532)(16,0.916174495807532)(17,0.916174495807532)(18,0.916174495807532)(19,0.923123748748984)(20,0.923123748748984)(21,0.923123748748984)(22,0.923123748748984)(23,0.923123748748984)(24,0.923123748748984)(25,0.923123748748984)(26,0.923123748748984)(27,0.923123748748984)(28,0.923123748748984)(29,0.923123748748984)(30,0.923123748748984)(31,0.923123748748984)(32,0.923123748748984)(33,0.923123748748984)(34,0.923123748748984)(35,0.923123748748984)(36,0.923123748748984)(37,0.923123748748984)(38,0.923123748748984)(39,0.923123748748984)(40,0.923123748748984)(41,0.923123748748984)(42,0.923123748748984)(43,0.923123748748984)(44,0.923123748748984)(45,0.923123748748984)(46,0.923123748748984)(47,0.923123748748984)(48,0.923123748748984)(49,0.923123748748984)(50,0.923123748748984)(51,0.923123748748984)(52,0.923123748748984)(53,0.923123748748984)(54,0.923123748748984)(55,0.923123748748984)(56,0.923123748748984)(57,0.923123748748984)(58,0.923123748748984)(59,0.923123748748984)(60,0.923123748748984)(61,0.923123748748984)(62,0.923123748748984)(63,0.928081390466589)(64,0.928770771366713)(65,0.928770771366713)(66,0.928770771366713)(67,0.928770771366713)(68,0.928770771366713)(69,0.928770771366713)(70,0.928770771366713)(71,0.928770771366713)(72,0.928770771366713)(73,0.928770771366713)(74,0.928770771366713)(75,0.928770771366713)(76,0.928770771366713)(77,0.928770771366713)(78,0.928770771366713)(79,0.928770771366713)(80,0.928770771366713)(81,0.928770771366713)(82,0.928770771366713)(83,0.928770771366713)(84,0.928770771366713)(85,0.928770771366713)(86,0.928770771366713)(87,0.928770771366713)(88,0.928770771366713)(89,0.928770771366713)(90,0.928770771366713)(91,0.928770771366713)(92,0.928770771366713)(93,0.929469960005271)(94,0.929469960005271)(95,0.929469960005271)(96,0.929469960005271)(97,0.929469960005271)(98,0.929469960005271)(99,0.929469960005271)(100,0.929469960005271)(101,0.929469960005271)(102,0.929469960005271)(103,0.929469960005271)(104,0.929469960005271)(105,0.929469960005271)(106,0.929469960005271)(107,0.929469960005271)(108,0.929469960005271)(109,0.929469960005271)(110,0.929469960005271)(111,0.929469960005271)(112,0.929469960005271)(113,0.929469960005271)(114,0.929469960005271)(115,0.929469960005271)(116,0.929469960005271)(117,0.929469960005271)(118,0.929469960005271)(119,0.929469960005271)(120,0.929469960005271)(121,0.929469960005271)(122,0.929469960005271)(123,0.929469960005271)(124,0.929469960005271)(125,0.929469960005271)(126,0.929469960005271)(127,0.929469960005271)(128,0.929469960005271)(129,0.929469960005271)(130,0.929469960005271)(131,0.929469960005271)(132,0.929469960005271)(133,0.929469960005271)(134,0.929469960005271)(135,0.929469960005271)(136,0.929469960005271)(137,0.929469960005271)(138,0.929469960005271)(139,0.929469960005271)(140,0.929469960005271)(141,0.929469960005271)(142,0.929469960005271)(143,0.929469960005271)(144,0.929469960005271)(145,0.929469960005271)(146,0.929469960005271)(147,0.929469960005271)(148,0.929469960005271)(149,0.929469960005271)(150,0.929469960005271)(151,0.929469960005271)(152,0.929469960005271)(153,0.929469960005271)(154,0.929469960005271)(155,0.929469960005271)(156,0.929469960005271)(157,0.929469960005271)(158,0.929469960005271)(159,0.929469960005271)(160,0.929469960005271)(161,0.929469960005271)(162,0.929469960005271)(163,0.929469960005271)(164,0.929469960005271)(165,0.929469960005271)(166,0.929469960005271)(167,0.929469960005271)(168,0.929469960005271)(169,0.929469960005271)(170,0.929469960005271)(171,0.929469960005271)(172,0.929469960005271)(173,0.929469960005271)(174,0.929469960005271)(175,0.929469960005271)(176,0.929469960005271)(177,0.929469960005271)(178,0.929469960005271)(179,0.929469960005271)(180,0.929469960005271)(181,0.929469960005271)(182,0.929469960005271)(183,0.929469960005271)(184,0.929469960005271)(185,0.929469960005271)(186,0.929469960005271)(187,0.929469960005271)(188,0.929469960005271)(189,0.929469960005271)(190,0.929469960005271)(191,0.929469960005271)(192,0.929469960005271)(193,0.929469960005271)(194,0.929469960005271)(195,0.929469960005271)(196,0.929469960005271)(197,0.932228612347654)(198,0.932228612347654)(199,0.932228612347654)(200,0.932228612347654)(201,0.932228612347654)(202,0.932228612347654)(203,0.932228612347654)(204,0.932228612347654)(205,0.932228612347654)(206,0.932228612347654)(207,0.932228612347654)(208,0.932228612347654)(209,0.932228612347654)(210,0.932228612347654)(211,0.932228612347654)(212,0.932228612347654)(213,0.932228612347654)(214,0.932228612347654)(215,0.932228612347654)(216,0.932228612347654)(217,0.932228612347654)(218,0.932228612347654)(219,0.932228612347654)(220,0.932228612347654)(221,0.932228612347654)(222,0.932228612347654)(223,0.932228612347654)(224,0.932228612347654)(225,0.932228612347654)(226,0.932228612347654)(227,0.932228612347654)(228,0.932228612347654)(229,0.932228612347654)(230,0.932228612347654)(231,0.932228612347654)(232,0.932228612347654)(233,0.932228612347654)(234,0.932228612347654)(235,0.932228612347654)(236,0.932228612347654)(237,0.932228612347654)(238,0.932228612347654)(239,0.932228612347654)(240,0.932228612347654)(241,0.932228612347654)(242,0.932228612347654)(243,0.932228612347654)(244,0.932228612347654)(245,0.932228612347654)(246,0.932228612347654)(247,0.932228612347654)(248,0.932228612347654)(249,0.932228612347654)(250,0.932228612347654)(251,0.932228612347654)(252,0.932228612347654)(253,0.932228612347654)(254,0.932228612347654)(255,0.932228612347654)(256,0.932228612347654)(257,0.932228612347654)(258,0.932228612347654)(259,0.932228612347654)(260,0.932228612347654)(261,0.932228612347654)(262,0.932228612347654)(263,0.932228612347654)(264,0.932228612347654)(265,0.932228612347654)(266,0.932228612347654)(267,0.932228612347654)(268,0.932228612347654)(269,0.932228612347654)(270,0.932228612347654)(271,0.932228612347654)(272,0.932228612347654)(273,0.932228612347654)(274,0.932228612347654)(275,0.932228612347654)(276,0.932228612347654)(277,0.932228612347654)(278,0.932228612347654)(279,0.932228612347654)(280,0.932228612347654)(281,0.932228612347654)(282,0.932228612347654)(283,0.932228612347654)(284,0.932228612347654)(285,0.932228612347654)(286,0.932228612347654)(287,0.932228612347654)(288,0.932228612347654)(289,0.932228612347654)(290,0.932228612347654)(291,0.932228612347654)(292,0.932228612347654)(293,0.932228612347654)(294,0.934752415889315)(295,0.934752415889315)(296,0.934752415889315)(297,0.934752415889315)(298,0.934752415889315)(299,0.934752415889315)};
\addplot plot coordinates{(0,0.340197581462877)(1,0.340197581462877)(2,0.340197581462877)(3,0.340197581462877)(4,0.340197581462877)(5,0.340197581462877)(6,0.340197581462877)(7,0.340197581462877)(8,0.340197581462877)(9,0.340197581462877)(10,0.340197581462877)(11,0.340197581462877)(12,0.340197581462877)(13,0.340197581462877)(14,0.340197581462877)(15,0.340197581462877)(16,0.340197581462877)(17,0.340197581462877)(18,0.340197581462877)(19,0.340197581462877)(20,0.340197581462877)(21,0.340197581462877)(22,0.340197581462877)(23,0.340197581462877)(24,0.340197581462877)(25,0.340197581462877)(26,0.340197581462877)(27,0.340197581462877)(28,0.340197581462877)(29,0.340197581462877)(30,0.340197581462877)(31,0.340197581462877)(32,0.340197581462877)(33,0.340197581462877)(34,0.340197581462877)(35,0.340197581462877)(36,0.340197581462877)(37,0.340197581462877)(38,0.340197581462877)(39,0.340197581462877)(40,0.340197581462877)(41,0.340197581462877)(42,0.340197581462877)(43,0.340197581462877)(44,0.340197581462877)(45,0.340197581462877)(46,0.340197581462877)(47,0.340197581462877)(48,0.340197581462877)(49,0.340197581462877)(50,0.340197581462877)(51,0.340197581462877)(52,0.340197581462877)(53,0.341579087464805)(54,0.341579087464805)(55,0.345096385457239)(56,0.345096385457239)(57,0.345096385457239)(58,0.345096385457239)(59,0.345096385457239)(60,0.345096385457239)(61,0.345096385457239)(62,0.345096385457239)(63,0.345096385457239)(64,0.345096385457239)(65,0.345096385457239)(66,0.345096385457239)(67,0.345096385457239)(68,0.345096385457239)(69,0.345096385457239)(70,0.345096385457239)(71,0.345096385457239)(72,0.345096385457239)(73,0.345096385457239)(74,0.345096385457239)(75,0.345096385457239)(76,0.345096385457239)(77,0.345096385457239)(78,0.345096385457239)(79,0.345096385457239)(80,0.345096385457239)(81,0.345096385457239)(82,0.345096385457239)(83,0.345096385457239)(84,0.345096385457239)(85,0.345096385457239)(86,0.345096385457239)(87,0.345096385457239)(88,0.345096385457239)(89,0.345096385457239)(90,0.345096385457239)(91,0.345096385457239)(92,0.345096385457239)(93,0.345096385457239)(94,0.345096385457239)(95,0.345096385457239)(96,0.345096385457239)(97,0.345096385457239)(98,0.345096385457239)(99,0.345096385457239)(100,0.345096385457239)(101,0.345096385457239)(102,0.345096385457239)(103,0.345096385457239)(104,0.345096385457239)(105,0.345096385457239)(106,0.345096385457239)(107,0.345096385457239)(108,0.345096385457239)(109,0.345096385457239)(110,0.923214304886365)(111,0.923214304886365)(112,0.923214304886365)(113,0.923214304886365)(114,0.933619414598761)(115,0.933619414598761)(116,0.933619414598761)(117,0.933619414598761)(118,0.936233644792674)(119,0.936233644792674)(120,0.936233644792674)(121,0.936233644792674)(122,0.936233644792674)(123,0.941115256469114)(124,0.941115256469114)(125,0.941115256469114)(126,0.941115256469114)(127,0.941115256469114)(128,0.941115256469114)(129,0.941115256469114)(130,0.941115256469114)(131,0.941221477176068)(132,0.941221477176068)(133,0.941221477176068)(134,0.944579485331057)(135,0.944579485331057)(136,0.944579485331057)(137,0.944579485331057)(138,0.944579485331057)(139,0.944579485331057)(140,0.944579485331057)(141,0.944579485331057)(142,0.944579485331057)(143,0.944579485331057)(144,0.944579485331057)(145,0.944579485331057)(146,0.944579485331057)(147,0.944579485331057)(148,0.944579485331057)(149,0.944579485331057)(150,0.944579485331057)(151,0.944579485331057)(152,0.944579485331057)(153,0.944579485331057)(154,0.944579485331057)(155,0.944579485331057)(156,0.944579485331057)(157,0.944579485331057)(158,0.944579485331057)(159,0.944579485331057)(160,0.944579485331057)(161,0.944579485331057)(162,0.944579485331057)(163,0.944579485331057)(164,0.944579485331057)(165,0.944579485331057)(166,0.944579485331057)(167,0.944579485331057)(168,0.944579485331057)(169,0.944579485331057)(170,0.944579485331057)(171,0.944579485331057)(172,0.944579485331057)(173,0.944579485331057)(174,0.944579485331057)(175,0.944579485331057)(176,0.944579485331057)(177,0.944579485331057)(178,0.944579485331057)(179,0.944579485331057)(180,0.944579485331057)(181,0.944579485331057)(182,0.944579485331057)(183,0.944579485331057)(184,0.944579485331057)(185,0.944579485331057)(186,0.944579485331057)(187,0.944579485331057)(188,0.944579485331057)(189,0.944579485331057)(190,0.944579485331057)(191,0.944579485331057)(192,0.944579485331057)(193,0.944579485331057)(194,0.944579485331057)(195,0.944579485331057)(196,0.944579485331057)(197,0.944579485331057)(198,0.944579485331057)(199,0.944579485331057)(200,0.944579485331057)(201,0.944579485331057)(202,0.944579485331057)(203,0.944579485331057)(204,0.944579485331057)(205,0.944579485331057)(206,0.944579485331057)(207,0.944579485331057)(208,0.944579485331057)(209,0.944579485331057)(210,0.944579485331057)(211,0.944579485331057)(212,0.944579485331057)(213,0.944579485331057)(214,0.944579485331057)(215,0.944579485331057)(216,0.944579485331057)(217,0.944579485331057)(218,0.944579485331057)(219,0.944579485331057)(220,0.944579485331057)(221,0.944579485331057)(222,0.944579485331057)(223,0.944579485331057)(224,0.944579485331057)(225,0.944579485331057)(226,0.944579485331057)(227,0.944579485331057)(228,0.944579485331057)(229,0.944579485331057)(230,0.944579485331057)(231,0.944579485331057)(232,0.944579485331057)(233,0.944579485331057)(234,0.944579485331057)(235,0.944579485331057)(236,0.944579485331057)(237,0.949135451187557)(238,0.949135451187557)(239,0.949135451187557)(240,0.949135451187557)(241,0.949135451187557)(242,0.949135451187557)(243,0.949135451187557)(244,0.949135451187557)(245,0.949135451187557)(246,0.949135451187557)(247,0.949135451187557)(248,0.949135451187557)(249,0.949135451187557)(250,0.949135451187557)(251,0.949135451187557)(252,0.949135451187557)(253,0.949135451187557)(254,0.949135451187557)(255,0.949135451187557)(256,0.949135451187557)(257,0.949135451187557)(258,0.949135451187557)(259,0.949135451187557)(260,0.949135451187557)(261,0.949135451187557)(262,0.949135451187557)(263,0.949135451187557)(264,0.949135451187557)(265,0.949135451187557)(266,0.949135451187557)(267,0.949135451187557)(268,0.949135451187557)(269,0.949135451187557)(270,0.949135451187557)(271,0.949135451187557)(272,0.949135451187557)(273,0.949135451187557)(274,0.949135451187557)(275,0.949135451187557)(276,0.949135451187557)(277,0.949135451187557)(278,0.949135451187557)(279,0.949135451187557)(280,0.949135451187557)(281,0.949135451187557)(282,0.949135451187557)(283,0.949135451187557)(284,0.949135451187557)(285,0.949135451187557)(286,0.949135451187557)(287,0.949135451187557)(288,0.949135451187557)(289,0.949135451187557)(290,0.949135451187557)(291,0.949135451187557)(292,0.949135451187557)(293,0.949135451187557)(294,0.949135451187557)(295,0.949135451187557)(296,0.949135451187557)(297,0.949135451187557)(298,0.949135451187557)(299,0.949135451187557)(300,0.949135451187557)(301,0.949135451187557)(302,0.949135451187557)};
\addplot plot coordinates{(0,0.340197581462877)(1,0.340197581462877)(2,0.340197581462877)(3,0.340197581462877)(4,0.340197581462877)(5,0.340197581462877)(6,0.340197581462877)(7,0.340197581462877)(8,0.340197581462877)(9,0.340197581462877)(10,0.340197581462877)(11,0.340197581462877)(12,0.340197581462877)(13,0.340197581462877)(14,0.340197581462877)(15,0.340197581462877)(16,0.340197581462877)(17,0.340197581462877)(18,0.340197581462877)(19,0.340197581462877)(20,0.340197581462877)(21,0.340197581462877)(22,0.340197581462877)(23,0.340197581462877)(24,0.340197581462877)(25,0.340197581462877)(26,0.340197581462877)(27,0.340197581462877)(28,0.340197581462877)(29,0.340197581462877)(30,0.340197581462877)(31,0.340197581462877)(32,0.340197581462877)(33,0.340197581462877)(34,0.340197581462877)(35,0.340197581462877)(36,0.340197581462877)(37,0.340197581462877)(38,0.340197581462877)(39,0.340197581462877)(40,0.340197581462877)(41,0.340197581462877)(42,0.340197581462877)(43,0.340197581462877)(44,0.340197581462877)(45,0.340197581462877)(46,0.340197581462877)(47,0.340197581462877)(48,0.340197581462877)(49,0.340197581462877)(50,0.340197581462877)(51,0.340197581462877)(52,0.340197581462877)(53,0.340197581462877)(54,0.340718810490398)(55,0.340947173204765)(56,0.340947173204765)(57,0.344557306311141)(58,0.344557306311141)(59,0.344557306311141)(60,0.344557306311141)(61,0.344557306311141)(62,0.344557306311141)(63,0.344557306311141)(64,0.345096385457239)(65,0.345096385457239)(66,0.345096385457239)(67,0.345096385457239)(68,0.345096385457239)(69,0.345096385457239)(70,0.345096385457239)(71,0.345096385457239)(72,0.345096385457239)(73,0.345096385457239)(74,0.345096385457239)(75,0.345096385457239)(76,0.345096385457239)(77,0.345096385457239)(78,0.345096385457239)(79,0.345096385457239)(80,0.345096385457239)(81,0.345096385457239)(82,0.345096385457239)(83,0.345096385457239)(84,0.345096385457239)(85,0.345096385457239)(86,0.345096385457239)(87,0.345096385457239)(88,0.345096385457239)(89,0.345096385457239)(90,0.345096385457239)(91,0.345096385457239)(92,0.345096385457239)(93,0.345096385457239)(94,0.345096385457239)(95,0.345096385457239)(96,0.345096385457239)(97,0.345096385457239)(98,0.345096385457239)(99,0.345096385457239)(100,0.345096385457239)(101,0.345096385457239)(102,0.345096385457239)(103,0.345096385457239)(104,0.345096385457239)(105,0.345096385457239)(106,0.345096385457239)(107,0.345096385457239)(108,0.345096385457239)(109,0.345096385457239)(110,0.345096385457239)(111,0.345096385457239)(112,0.345096385457239)(113,0.345096385457239)(114,0.345096385457239)(115,0.345096385457239)(116,0.345096385457239)(117,0.345096385457239)(118,0.345096385457239)(119,0.345096385457239)(120,0.345096385457239)(121,0.93346075957151)(122,0.938259689585135)(123,0.938259689585135)(124,0.938259689585135)(125,0.940212485558681)(126,0.940212485558681)(127,0.940212485558681)(128,0.940212485558681)(129,0.940717035777305)(130,0.940717035777305)(131,0.940717035777305)(132,0.940717035777305)(133,0.940717035777305)(134,0.940717035777305)(135,0.940717035777305)(136,0.940717035777305)(137,0.940717035777305)(138,0.940717035777305)(139,0.940717035777305)(140,0.940717035777305)(141,0.940717035777305)(142,0.940717035777305)(143,0.940717035777305)(144,0.940717035777305)(145,0.940717035777305)(146,0.940717035777305)(147,0.940717035777305)(148,0.943137433357112)(149,0.943137433357112)(150,0.943137433357112)(151,0.943137433357112)(152,0.943137433357112)(153,0.943137433357112)(154,0.943137433357112)(155,0.943137433357112)(156,0.943137433357112)(157,0.943137433357112)(158,0.943137433357112)(159,0.943137433357112)(160,0.943137433357112)(161,0.943137433357112)(162,0.943137433357112)(163,0.943137433357112)(164,0.943137433357112)(165,0.943137433357112)(166,0.943137433357112)(167,0.943137433357112)(168,0.943137433357112)(169,0.943137433357112)(170,0.943137433357112)(171,0.943824129539037)(172,0.943824129539037)(173,0.943824129539037)(174,0.943824129539037)(175,0.943824129539037)(176,0.943824129539037)(177,0.943824129539037)(178,0.943824129539037)(179,0.943824129539037)(180,0.943824129539037)(181,0.943824129539037)(182,0.943824129539037)(183,0.943824129539037)(184,0.943824129539037)(185,0.943824129539037)(186,0.943824129539037)(187,0.943824129539037)(188,0.943824129539037)(189,0.943824129539037)(190,0.943824129539037)(191,0.943824129539037)(192,0.943824129539037)(193,0.943824129539037)(194,0.943824129539037)(195,0.943824129539037)(196,0.943824129539037)(197,0.943824129539037)(198,0.943824129539037)(199,0.943824129539037)(200,0.943824129539037)(201,0.943824129539037)(202,0.943824129539037)(203,0.943824129539037)(204,0.943824129539037)(205,0.943824129539037)(206,0.944473264624103)(207,0.944473264624103)(208,0.944473264624103)(209,0.944473264624103)(210,0.944473264624103)(211,0.944473264624103)(212,0.944473264624103)(213,0.944473264624103)(214,0.944473264624103)(215,0.944473264624103)(216,0.944473264624103)(217,0.944473264624103)(218,0.944473264624103)(219,0.944473264624103)(220,0.944473264624103)(221,0.944473264624103)(222,0.944473264624103)(223,0.944473264624103)(224,0.944473264624103)(225,0.944473264624103)(226,0.944473264624103)(227,0.944473264624103)(228,0.944473264624103)(229,0.944473264624103)(230,0.944473264624103)(231,0.944473264624103)(232,0.944473264624103)(233,0.944473264624103)(234,0.944473264624103)(235,0.944473264624103)(236,0.944473264624103)(237,0.944473264624103)(238,0.944473264624103)(239,0.944473264624103)(240,0.944473264624103)(241,0.944473264624103)(242,0.944473264624103)(243,0.944473264624103)(244,0.944473264624103)(245,0.944579485331057)(246,0.944579485331057)(247,0.944579485331057)(248,0.944579485331057)(249,0.944579485331057)(250,0.944579485331057)(251,0.944579485331057)(252,0.944579485331057)(253,0.944579485331057)(254,0.944579485331057)(255,0.944579485331057)(256,0.944579485331057)(257,0.944579485331057)(258,0.944579485331057)(259,0.944579485331057)(260,0.944579485331057)(261,0.944579485331057)(262,0.944579485331057)(263,0.944579485331057)(264,0.944579485331057)(265,0.944579485331057)(266,0.944579485331057)(267,0.944579485331057)(268,0.944579485331057)(269,0.944579485331057)(270,0.944579485331057)(271,0.944579485331057)(272,0.944579485331057)(273,0.944579485331057)(274,0.944579485331057)(275,0.944579485331057)(276,0.944579485331057)(277,0.944579485331057)(278,0.944579485331057)(279,0.944579485331057)(280,0.944579485331057)(281,0.944579485331057)(282,0.944579485331057)(283,0.944579485331057)(284,0.944579485331057)(285,0.944579485331057)(286,0.944579485331057)(287,0.944579485331057)(288,0.944579485331057)(289,0.944579485331057)(290,0.944579485331057)(291,0.944579485331057)(292,0.944579485331057)(293,0.944579485331057)(294,0.944579485331057)(295,0.944579485331057)(296,0.944579485331057)(297,0.944579485331057)(298,0.944579485331057)(299,0.944579485331057)(300,0.944579485331057)(301,0.944579485331057)};
\legend{a,b,c,d}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: you can say `\addplot[color]` and it will only draw the lines no markers. You will need to specify the color for each curve. You can also say `\addplot[mark=none]` but that will make all curves black.

Comment: You can add the option `no markers` to the `axis` environment.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `mark=none`; personally I would create a style for this

```
\pgfplotsset{mystyle/.style={mark=none}}
```

which can be used as

```
\addplot[mystyle]....
```

or, if you wish to inherit the existing styles, or otherwise-created `cycle list`, then you can use

```
\addplot+[mystyle]....
```

In the code below, I have used `\addplot+`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\pgfplotsset{
    xticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
    every axis/.append style={
        font=\sffamily,
        title style={font=\bfseries\sffamily}, 
        width=6.5cm,
        height=4.9cm
    }
}

\pgfplotsset{mystyle/.style={mark=none}}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[title=QWS Dataset,
        legend pos=outer north east,
        ytick={0,0.2,...,1},
        legend pos=outer north east,
        legend style={draw=none},
        xtick={0,200,...,1000},
        scaled ticks=false,
        log ticks with fixed point={1000 sep=},
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        axis line style=-,
        minor tick style={draw=none},
        ylabel = Optimality (\%),
        xlabel = Number of Generation
        ]
        \addplot+[mystyle] plot coordinates{(0,0.286803995268681)(0,0.293986647767033)(1,0.293986647767033)(2,0.293986647767033)(3,0.293986647767033)(4,0.296941042144544)(5,0.296941042144544)(6,0.840289302662629)(7,0.883725575957752)(8,0.883725575957752)(9,0.883725575957752)(10,0.883725575957752)(11,0.888401316547969)(12,0.888401316547969)(13,0.888401316547969)(14,0.888401316547969)(15,0.888401316547969)(16,0.888401316547969)(17,0.888401316547969)(18,0.888401316547969)(19,0.888401316547969)(20,0.888401316547969)(21,0.888401316547969)(22,0.888401316547969)(23,0.888401316547969)(24,0.888401316547969)(25,0.888401316547969)(26,0.888401316547969)(27,0.888401316547969)(28,0.888401316547969)(29,0.888401316547969)(30,0.888401316547969)(31,0.888401316547969)(32,0.888401316547969)(33,0.888401316547969)(34,0.888401316547969)(35,0.888549662438951)(36,0.888549662438951)(37,0.888549662438951)(38,0.888549662438951)(39,0.894067099804665)(40,0.894067099804665)(41,0.894067099804665)(42,0.894067099804665)(43,0.894067099804665)(44,0.894067099804665)(45,0.894067099804665)(46,0.894147773567333)(47,0.894147773567333)(48,0.901221579313708)(49,0.901221579313708)(50,0.901221579313708)(51,0.901221579313708)(52,0.913119929645424)(53,0.913119929645424)(54,0.913119929645424)(55,0.913119929645424)(56,0.913119929645424)(57,0.913119929645424)(58,0.913119929645424)(59,0.913119929645424)(60,0.913119929645424)(61,0.913119929645424)(62,0.913119929645424)(63,0.913119929645424)(64,0.913119929645424)(65,0.913119929645424)(66,0.913119929645424)(67,0.913119929645424)(68,0.913119929645424)(69,0.913119929645424)(70,0.913119929645424)(71,0.913119929645424)(72,0.913119929645424)(73,0.913119929645424)(74,0.913119929645424)(75,0.913119929645424)(76,0.913119929645424)(77,0.913119929645424)(78,0.913119929645424)(79,0.913119929645424)(80,0.913119929645424)(81,0.913119929645424)(82,0.913119929645424)(83,0.913119929645424)(84,0.913119929645424)(85,0.913119929645424)(86,0.913119929645424)(87,0.913119929645424)(88,0.913119929645424)(89,0.913119929645424)(90,0.913119929645424)(91,0.913119929645424)(92,0.913119929645424)(93,0.913119929645424)(94,0.913119929645424)(95,0.913119929645424)(96,0.913119929645424)(97,0.913119929645424)(98,0.913119929645424)(99,0.913119929645424)(100,0.913119929645424)(101,0.913119929645424)(102,0.913119929645424)(103,0.913119929645424)(104,0.913119929645424)(105,0.913119929645424)(106,0.913119929645424)(107,0.913119929645424)(108,0.913119929645424)(109,0.913119929645424)(110,0.913119929645424)(111,0.913119929645424)(112,0.913119929645424)(113,0.913119929645424)(114,0.913119929645424)(115,0.913119929645424)(116,0.913119929645424)(117,0.913119929645424)(118,0.913119929645424)(119,0.913119929645424)(120,0.913119929645424)(121,0.913119929645424)(122,0.913119929645424)(123,0.913119929645424)(124,0.913119929645424)(125,0.913119929645424)(126,0.913119929645424)(127,0.913119929645424)(128,0.913119929645424)(129,0.913119929645424)(130,0.913119929645424)(131,0.913119929645424)(132,0.913119929645424)(133,0.913119929645424)(134,0.913119929645424)(135,0.913119929645424)(136,0.913119929645424)(137,0.913119929645424)(138,0.913119929645424)(139,0.913119929645424)(140,0.913119929645424)(141,0.913119929645424)(142,0.913119929645424)(143,0.913119929645424)(144,0.913119929645424)(145,0.913119929645424)(146,0.913119929645424)(147,0.913119929645424)(148,0.913119929645424)(149,0.913119929645424)(150,0.913119929645424)(151,0.913119929645424)(152,0.913119929645424)(153,0.913119929645424)(154,0.913119929645424)(155,0.913119929645424)(156,0.913119929645424)(157,0.913119929645424)(158,0.913119929645424)(159,0.913119929645424)(160,0.913119929645424)(161,0.913119929645424)(162,0.913119929645424)(163,0.913119929645424)(164,0.913119929645424)(165,0.913119929645424)(166,0.913119929645424)(167,0.913119929645424)(168,0.913119929645424)(169,0.913119929645424)(170,0.913119929645424)(171,0.913119929645424)(172,0.913119929645424)(173,0.913119929645424)(174,0.913119929645424)(175,0.913119929645424)(176,0.913119929645424)(177,0.913119929645424)(178,0.913119929645424)(179,0.913119929645424)(180,0.913119929645424)(181,0.913119929645424)(182,0.913119929645424)(183,0.913119929645424)(184,0.913119929645424)(185,0.913119929645424)(186,0.913119929645424)(187,0.913119929645424)(188,0.913119929645424)(189,0.913119929645424)(190,0.913119929645424)(191,0.913119929645424)(192,0.913119929645424)(193,0.913119929645424)(194,0.913119929645424)(195,0.913119929645424)(196,0.913119929645424)(197,0.913119929645424)(198,0.913119929645424)(199,0.913119929645424)(200,0.913119929645424)(201,0.913119929645424)(202,0.913951685219313)(203,0.913951685219313)(204,0.913951685219313)(205,0.913951685219313)(206,0.913951685219313)(207,0.913951685219313)(208,0.913951685219313)(209,0.913951685219313)(210,0.913951685219313)(211,0.913951685219313)(212,0.913951685219313)(213,0.913951685219313)(214,0.913951685219313)(215,0.913951685219313)(216,0.913951685219313)(217,0.913951685219313)(218,0.913951685219313)(219,0.913951685219313)(220,0.913951685219313)(221,0.913951685219313)(222,0.913951685219313)(223,0.913951685219313)(224,0.913951685219313)(225,0.913951685219313)(226,0.913951685219313)(227,0.913951685219313)(228,0.913951685219313)(229,0.913951685219313)(230,0.913951685219313)(231,0.913951685219313)(232,0.926293607531258)(233,0.926293607531258)(234,0.926293607531258)(235,0.926293607531258)(236,0.926293607531258)(237,0.926293607531258)(238,0.926293607531258)(239,0.926293607531258)(240,0.926293607531258)(241,0.926293607531258)(242,0.926293607531258)(243,0.926293607531258)(244,0.926293607531258)(245,0.926293607531258)(246,0.926293607531258)(247,0.926293607531258)(248,0.926293607531258)(249,0.926293607531258)(250,0.926293607531258)(251,0.926293607531258)(252,0.926293607531258)(253,0.926293607531258)(254,0.926293607531258)(255,0.926293607531258)(256,0.926293607531258)(257,0.926293607531258)(258,0.926293607531258)(259,0.926293607531258)(260,0.926293607531258)(261,0.926293607531258)(262,0.926293607531258)(263,0.926293607531258)(264,0.926293607531258)(265,0.926293607531258)(266,0.926293607531258)(267,0.926293607531258)(268,0.926293607531258)(269,0.926293607531258)(270,0.926293607531258)(271,0.926293607531258)(272,0.926293607531258)(273,0.926293607531258)(274,0.926293607531258)(275,0.926293607531258)(276,0.926293607531258)(277,0.926293607531258)(278,0.926293607531258)(279,0.926293607531258)(280,0.926293607531258)(281,0.926293607531258)(282,0.926293607531258)(283,0.926293607531258)(284,0.926293607531258)(285,0.926293607531258)(286,0.926293607531258)(287,0.926293607531258)(288,0.926293607531258)(289,0.926293607531258)(290,0.926293607531258)(291,0.926293607531258)(292,0.926293607531258)(293,0.926293607531258)(294,0.926293607531258)(295,0.926293607531258)(296,0.926293607531258)(297,0.926293607531258)(298,0.926293607531258)(299,0.926293607531258)(300,0.926293607531258)(301,0.926293607531258)(302,0.926293607531258)(303,0.926293607531258)(304,0.926293607531258)(305,0.926293607531258)};
        \addplot+[mystyle] plot coordinates{(0,0.893138221303528)(0,0.897063840513733)(1,0.909783376964972)(2,0.909783376964972)(3,0.909783376964972)(4,0.909783376964972)(5,0.909783376964972)(6,0.909783376964972)(7,0.916174495807532)(8,0.916174495807532)(9,0.916174495807532)(10,0.916174495807532)(11,0.916174495807532)(12,0.916174495807532)(13,0.916174495807532)(14,0.916174495807532)(15,0.916174495807532)(16,0.916174495807532)(17,0.916174495807532)(18,0.916174495807532)(19,0.923123748748984)(20,0.923123748748984)(21,0.923123748748984)(22,0.923123748748984)(23,0.923123748748984)(24,0.923123748748984)(25,0.923123748748984)(26,0.923123748748984)(27,0.923123748748984)(28,0.923123748748984)(29,0.923123748748984)(30,0.923123748748984)(31,0.923123748748984)(32,0.923123748748984)(33,0.923123748748984)(34,0.923123748748984)(35,0.923123748748984)(36,0.923123748748984)(37,0.923123748748984)(38,0.923123748748984)(39,0.923123748748984)(40,0.923123748748984)(41,0.923123748748984)(42,0.923123748748984)(43,0.923123748748984)(44,0.923123748748984)(45,0.923123748748984)(46,0.923123748748984)(47,0.923123748748984)(48,0.923123748748984)(49,0.923123748748984)(50,0.923123748748984)(51,0.923123748748984)(52,0.923123748748984)(53,0.923123748748984)(54,0.923123748748984)(55,0.923123748748984)(56,0.923123748748984)(57,0.923123748748984)(58,0.923123748748984)(59,0.923123748748984)(60,0.923123748748984)(61,0.923123748748984)(62,0.923123748748984)(63,0.928081390466589)(64,0.928770771366713)(65,0.928770771366713)(66,0.928770771366713)(67,0.928770771366713)(68,0.928770771366713)(69,0.928770771366713)(70,0.928770771366713)(71,0.928770771366713)(72,0.928770771366713)(73,0.928770771366713)(74,0.928770771366713)(75,0.928770771366713)(76,0.928770771366713)(77,0.928770771366713)(78,0.928770771366713)(79,0.928770771366713)(80,0.928770771366713)(81,0.928770771366713)(82,0.928770771366713)(83,0.928770771366713)(84,0.928770771366713)(85,0.928770771366713)(86,0.928770771366713)(87,0.928770771366713)(88,0.928770771366713)(89,0.928770771366713)(90,0.928770771366713)(91,0.928770771366713)(92,0.928770771366713)(93,0.929469960005271)(94,0.929469960005271)(95,0.929469960005271)(96,0.929469960005271)(97,0.929469960005271)(98,0.929469960005271)(99,0.929469960005271)(100,0.929469960005271)(101,0.929469960005271)(102,0.929469960005271)(103,0.929469960005271)(104,0.929469960005271)(105,0.929469960005271)(106,0.929469960005271)(107,0.929469960005271)(108,0.929469960005271)(109,0.929469960005271)(110,0.929469960005271)(111,0.929469960005271)(112,0.929469960005271)(113,0.929469960005271)(114,0.929469960005271)(115,0.929469960005271)(116,0.929469960005271)(117,0.929469960005271)(118,0.929469960005271)(119,0.929469960005271)(120,0.929469960005271)(121,0.929469960005271)(122,0.929469960005271)(123,0.929469960005271)(124,0.929469960005271)(125,0.929469960005271)(126,0.929469960005271)(127,0.929469960005271)(128,0.929469960005271)(129,0.929469960005271)(130,0.929469960005271)(131,0.929469960005271)(132,0.929469960005271)(133,0.929469960005271)(134,0.929469960005271)(135,0.929469960005271)(136,0.929469960005271)(137,0.929469960005271)(138,0.929469960005271)(139,0.929469960005271)(140,0.929469960005271)(141,0.929469960005271)(142,0.929469960005271)(143,0.929469960005271)(144,0.929469960005271)(145,0.929469960005271)(146,0.929469960005271)(147,0.929469960005271)(148,0.929469960005271)(149,0.929469960005271)(150,0.929469960005271)(151,0.929469960005271)(152,0.929469960005271)(153,0.929469960005271)(154,0.929469960005271)(155,0.929469960005271)(156,0.929469960005271)(157,0.929469960005271)(158,0.929469960005271)(159,0.929469960005271)(160,0.929469960005271)(161,0.929469960005271)(162,0.929469960005271)(163,0.929469960005271)(164,0.929469960005271)(165,0.929469960005271)(166,0.929469960005271)(167,0.929469960005271)(168,0.929469960005271)(169,0.929469960005271)(170,0.929469960005271)(171,0.929469960005271)(172,0.929469960005271)(173,0.929469960005271)(174,0.929469960005271)(175,0.929469960005271)(176,0.929469960005271)(177,0.929469960005271)(178,0.929469960005271)(179,0.929469960005271)(180,0.929469960005271)(181,0.929469960005271)(182,0.929469960005271)(183,0.929469960005271)(184,0.929469960005271)(185,0.929469960005271)(186,0.929469960005271)(187,0.929469960005271)(188,0.929469960005271)(189,0.929469960005271)(190,0.929469960005271)(191,0.929469960005271)(192,0.929469960005271)(193,0.929469960005271)(194,0.929469960005271)(195,0.929469960005271)(196,0.929469960005271)(197,0.932228612347654)(198,0.932228612347654)(199,0.932228612347654)(200,0.932228612347654)(201,0.932228612347654)(202,0.932228612347654)(203,0.932228612347654)(204,0.932228612347654)(205,0.932228612347654)(206,0.932228612347654)(207,0.932228612347654)(208,0.932228612347654)(209,0.932228612347654)(210,0.932228612347654)(211,0.932228612347654)(212,0.932228612347654)(213,0.932228612347654)(214,0.932228612347654)(215,0.932228612347654)(216,0.932228612347654)(217,0.932228612347654)(218,0.932228612347654)(219,0.932228612347654)(220,0.932228612347654)(221,0.932228612347654)(222,0.932228612347654)(223,0.932228612347654)(224,0.932228612347654)(225,0.932228612347654)(226,0.932228612347654)(227,0.932228612347654)(228,0.932228612347654)(229,0.932228612347654)(230,0.932228612347654)(231,0.932228612347654)(232,0.932228612347654)(233,0.932228612347654)(234,0.932228612347654)(235,0.932228612347654)(236,0.932228612347654)(237,0.932228612347654)(238,0.932228612347654)(239,0.932228612347654)(240,0.932228612347654)(241,0.932228612347654)(242,0.932228612347654)(243,0.932228612347654)(244,0.932228612347654)(245,0.932228612347654)(246,0.932228612347654)(247,0.932228612347654)(248,0.932228612347654)(249,0.932228612347654)(250,0.932228612347654)(251,0.932228612347654)(252,0.932228612347654)(253,0.932228612347654)(254,0.932228612347654)(255,0.932228612347654)(256,0.932228612347654)(257,0.932228612347654)(258,0.932228612347654)(259,0.932228612347654)(260,0.932228612347654)(261,0.932228612347654)(262,0.932228612347654)(263,0.932228612347654)(264,0.932228612347654)(265,0.932228612347654)(266,0.932228612347654)(267,0.932228612347654)(268,0.932228612347654)(269,0.932228612347654)(270,0.932228612347654)(271,0.932228612347654)(272,0.932228612347654)(273,0.932228612347654)(274,0.932228612347654)(275,0.932228612347654)(276,0.932228612347654)(277,0.932228612347654)(278,0.932228612347654)(279,0.932228612347654)(280,0.932228612347654)(281,0.932228612347654)(282,0.932228612347654)(283,0.932228612347654)(284,0.932228612347654)(285,0.932228612347654)(286,0.932228612347654)(287,0.932228612347654)(288,0.932228612347654)(289,0.932228612347654)(290,0.932228612347654)(291,0.932228612347654)(292,0.932228612347654)(293,0.932228612347654)(294,0.934752415889315)(295,0.934752415889315)(296,0.934752415889315)(297,0.934752415889315)(298,0.934752415889315)(299,0.934752415889315)};
        \addplot+[mystyle] plot coordinates{(0,0.340197581462877)(1,0.340197581462877)(2,0.340197581462877)(3,0.340197581462877)(4,0.340197581462877)(5,0.340197581462877)(6,0.340197581462877)(7,0.340197581462877)(8,0.340197581462877)(9,0.340197581462877)(10,0.340197581462877)(11,0.340197581462877)(12,0.340197581462877)(13,0.340197581462877)(14,0.340197581462877)(15,0.340197581462877)(16,0.340197581462877)(17,0.340197581462877)(18,0.340197581462877)(19,0.340197581462877)(20,0.340197581462877)(21,0.340197581462877)(22,0.340197581462877)(23,0.340197581462877)(24,0.340197581462877)(25,0.340197581462877)(26,0.340197581462877)(27,0.340197581462877)(28,0.340197581462877)(29,0.340197581462877)(30,0.340197581462877)(31,0.340197581462877)(32,0.340197581462877)(33,0.340197581462877)(34,0.340197581462877)(35,0.340197581462877)(36,0.340197581462877)(37,0.340197581462877)(38,0.340197581462877)(39,0.340197581462877)(40,0.340197581462877)(41,0.340197581462877)(42,0.340197581462877)(43,0.340197581462877)(44,0.340197581462877)(45,0.340197581462877)(46,0.340197581462877)(47,0.340197581462877)(48,0.340197581462877)(49,0.340197581462877)(50,0.340197581462877)(51,0.340197581462877)(52,0.340197581462877)(53,0.341579087464805)(54,0.341579087464805)(55,0.345096385457239)(56,0.345096385457239)(57,0.345096385457239)(58,0.345096385457239)(59,0.345096385457239)(60,0.345096385457239)(61,0.345096385457239)(62,0.345096385457239)(63,0.345096385457239)(64,0.345096385457239)(65,0.345096385457239)(66,0.345096385457239)(67,0.345096385457239)(68,0.345096385457239)(69,0.345096385457239)(70,0.345096385457239)(71,0.345096385457239)(72,0.345096385457239)(73,0.345096385457239)(74,0.345096385457239)(75,0.345096385457239)(76,0.345096385457239)(77,0.345096385457239)(78,0.345096385457239)(79,0.345096385457239)(80,0.345096385457239)(81,0.345096385457239)(82,0.345096385457239)(83,0.345096385457239)(84,0.345096385457239)(85,0.345096385457239)(86,0.345096385457239)(87,0.345096385457239)(88,0.345096385457239)(89,0.345096385457239)(90,0.345096385457239)(91,0.345096385457239)(92,0.345096385457239)(93,0.345096385457239)(94,0.345096385457239)(95,0.345096385457239)(96,0.345096385457239)(97,0.345096385457239)(98,0.345096385457239)(99,0.345096385457239)(100,0.345096385457239)(101,0.345096385457239)(102,0.345096385457239)(103,0.345096385457239)(104,0.345096385457239)(105,0.345096385457239)(106,0.345096385457239)(107,0.345096385457239)(108,0.345096385457239)(109,0.345096385457239)(110,0.923214304886365)(111,0.923214304886365)(112,0.923214304886365)(113,0.923214304886365)(114,0.933619414598761)(115,0.933619414598761)(116,0.933619414598761)(117,0.933619414598761)(118,0.936233644792674)(119,0.936233644792674)(120,0.936233644792674)(121,0.936233644792674)(122,0.936233644792674)(123,0.941115256469114)(124,0.941115256469114)(125,0.941115256469114)(126,0.941115256469114)(127,0.941115256469114)(128,0.941115256469114)(129,0.941115256469114)(130,0.941115256469114)(131,0.941221477176068)(132,0.941221477176068)(133,0.941221477176068)(134,0.944579485331057)(135,0.944579485331057)(136,0.944579485331057)(137,0.944579485331057)(138,0.944579485331057)(139,0.944579485331057)(140,0.944579485331057)(141,0.944579485331057)(142,0.944579485331057)(143,0.944579485331057)(144,0.944579485331057)(145,0.944579485331057)(146,0.944579485331057)(147,0.944579485331057)(148,0.944579485331057)(149,0.944579485331057)(150,0.944579485331057)(151,0.944579485331057)(152,0.944579485331057)(153,0.944579485331057)(154,0.944579485331057)(155,0.944579485331057)(156,0.944579485331057)(157,0.944579485331057)(158,0.944579485331057)(159,0.944579485331057)(160,0.944579485331057)(161,0.944579485331057)(162,0.944579485331057)(163,0.944579485331057)(164,0.944579485331057)(165,0.944579485331057)(166,0.944579485331057)(167,0.944579485331057)(168,0.944579485331057)(169,0.944579485331057)(170,0.944579485331057)(171,0.944579485331057)(172,0.944579485331057)(173,0.944579485331057)(174,0.944579485331057)(175,0.944579485331057)(176,0.944579485331057)(177,0.944579485331057)(178,0.944579485331057)(179,0.944579485331057)(180,0.944579485331057)(181,0.944579485331057)(182,0.944579485331057)(183,0.944579485331057)(184,0.944579485331057)(185,0.944579485331057)(186,0.944579485331057)(187,0.944579485331057)(188,0.944579485331057)(189,0.944579485331057)(190,0.944579485331057)(191,0.944579485331057)(192,0.944579485331057)(193,0.944579485331057)(194,0.944579485331057)(195,0.944579485331057)(196,0.944579485331057)(197,0.944579485331057)(198,0.944579485331057)(199,0.944579485331057)(200,0.944579485331057)(201,0.944579485331057)(202,0.944579485331057)(203,0.944579485331057)(204,0.944579485331057)(205,0.944579485331057)(206,0.944579485331057)(207,0.944579485331057)(208,0.944579485331057)(209,0.944579485331057)(210,0.944579485331057)(211,0.944579485331057)(212,0.944579485331057)(213,0.944579485331057)(214,0.944579485331057)(215,0.944579485331057)(216,0.944579485331057)(217,0.944579485331057)(218,0.944579485331057)(219,0.944579485331057)(220,0.944579485331057)(221,0.944579485331057)(222,0.944579485331057)(223,0.944579485331057)(224,0.944579485331057)(225,0.944579485331057)(226,0.944579485331057)(227,0.944579485331057)(228,0.944579485331057)(229,0.944579485331057)(230,0.944579485331057)(231,0.944579485331057)(232,0.944579485331057)(233,0.944579485331057)(234,0.944579485331057)(235,0.944579485331057)(236,0.944579485331057)(237,0.949135451187557)(238,0.949135451187557)(239,0.949135451187557)(240,0.949135451187557)(241,0.949135451187557)(242,0.949135451187557)(243,0.949135451187557)(244,0.949135451187557)(245,0.949135451187557)(246,0.949135451187557)(247,0.949135451187557)(248,0.949135451187557)(249,0.949135451187557)(250,0.949135451187557)(251,0.949135451187557)(252,0.949135451187557)(253,0.949135451187557)(254,0.949135451187557)(255,0.949135451187557)(256,0.949135451187557)(257,0.949135451187557)(258,0.949135451187557)(259,0.949135451187557)(260,0.949135451187557)(261,0.949135451187557)(262,0.949135451187557)(263,0.949135451187557)(264,0.949135451187557)(265,0.949135451187557)(266,0.949135451187557)(267,0.949135451187557)(268,0.949135451187557)(269,0.949135451187557)(270,0.949135451187557)(271,0.949135451187557)(272,0.949135451187557)(273,0.949135451187557)(274,0.949135451187557)(275,0.949135451187557)(276,0.949135451187557)(277,0.949135451187557)(278,0.949135451187557)(279,0.949135451187557)(280,0.949135451187557)(281,0.949135451187557)(282,0.949135451187557)(283,0.949135451187557)(284,0.949135451187557)(285,0.949135451187557)(286,0.949135451187557)(287,0.949135451187557)(288,0.949135451187557)(289,0.949135451187557)(290,0.949135451187557)(291,0.949135451187557)(292,0.949135451187557)(293,0.949135451187557)(294,0.949135451187557)(295,0.949135451187557)(296,0.949135451187557)(297,0.949135451187557)(298,0.949135451187557)(299,0.949135451187557)(300,0.949135451187557)(301,0.949135451187557)(302,0.949135451187557)};

        \legend{a,b,c,d}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you want to create your own `cycle list` then you can use something like the following

```
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycyclelist}{%
color=red,mark=none,line width=1pt,\\%
color=blue,mark=none,line width=2pt,\\%
color=gray,mark=none,line width=3pt,\\%
color=purple,dashed,mark=none,line width=1pt,\\%
}

\pgfplotsset{
    xticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
    every axis/.append style={
        font=\sffamily,
        title style={font=\bfseries\sffamily}, 
        width=6.5cm,
        height=4.9cm,
        cycle list name=mycyclelist,
    }
}
```

Whenever you use `\addplot+[mystyle]...` it will inherit the styles that you have specified *in order* from the `cycle list`; so the first line will be `red`, the second will be `blue`, the third will be `gray`, the fourth will be `purple`, (and `dashed`) and the fifth will go back to `red`.

[image: screenshot]

Note that using `\addplot[mystyle]...` (without the `+`) will ignore the `cycle list`.